# Getting Incorrect SUM for left joins and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I am getting wrong results in the sum of total deposits.
I want to output a report of total deposits per campaign_name
and eventually inside a date range.

```
 SELECT IFNULL(campaign_name,'DIRECT'),
       IFNULL(TotalDeposit,0)
FROM trackings
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT deposit_amount,
          sum(deposit_amount) AS TotalDeposit,
          uuid
   FROM conversions
   LEFT JOIN transactions ON conversions.trader_id = transactions.trader_id
   WHERE aff_id =3
     AND TYPE='deposit'
   GROUP BY transactions.trader_id) AS conversions ON trackings.uuid = conversions.uuid
WHERE aff_id=3
GROUP BY campaign_name
```

results: missing 200 from trynow campaign??

```
campaign_name,TotalDeposit
DIRECT,0.00
new_campaign_name,0.00
test march,500.00
testing,0.00
trynow,800.00
```

expected results:

```
campaign_name,TotalDeposit    
DIRECT,0.00
new_campaign_name,0.00
test march,500.00
testing,0.00
trynow,1000.00
```

Comment: It may be helpful to populate the sample data into an SqlFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) so people can play around with it.  I know I am usually better able to figure out what's going on looking at data than just looking at the query!

Comment: Your expected results are rather useless without sample data.

Comment: nested select looks inconsistent. it's grouped by just one field transactions.trader_id meanwhile there are 2 more fields in SELECT clause.

Comment: also, double WHERE aff_id=3 looks redundant

Comment: I'm getting a script error in SQLFiddle for some reason

Comment: I pasted the sample schemas and data here http://laravel.io/bin/mGB2v

Answer (score 0):

I think your data isn't quite right - using the data that you've supplied, the deposit of 500 for test march is never going to be returned, as it is linked to trader_id 7506, who has no records in the conversions table.

However, the following query is simpler and easier to understand, and correctly returns 1000 for trynow

```
SELECT
      IFNULL(SUM(t.deposit_amount),0) AS total_deposits
    , IFNULL(tr.campaign_name,'DIRECT') AS campaign


FROM
    trackings tr            LEFT JOIN

    conversions c ON
        tr.uuid = c.uuid    LEFT JOIN

    transactions t ON
        c.trader_id = t.trader_id AND
        tr.`aff_id` = t.aff_id AND
        t.type = 'Deposit' 

WHERE
    tr.aff_id = 3  AND
    tr.updated_at >= '2015-03-01' AND tr.updated_at < '2015-04-01'

GROUP BY
    IFNULL(tr.campaign_name,'DIRECT')
```

If you can check the test data supplied or otherwise point me in the right direction, I might be able to improve the query to return exactly what you want.

For date filtering, see the addition to the where clause above. NOte that if you need to filter on a date in the transactions table, the date filtering clause must be part of the "on" statement instead (as this table is left-joined, so we can't filter in the main where clause).

Comment: Simon, thanks this returns the correct result, In addition I tried to add an affiliate_commissions table http://laravel.io/bin/E3e5m  according to your syntax but the deposit for trynow got quadrupled And how would I add a calendar table to check campaign_name totalDeposits between a date range? and any remarks regarding my table structure would be greatly appreciated as I am surely doing something wrong.

Comment: The table structure seems rather complex for what it is, but I haven't spent a long time trying to understand the business case behind it. Coming up with the ideal structure is probably a seperate question, as we have solved the issue you originally had here.

Comment: See my additional comments in the answer above, re: date filtering and double counting issues.

If this answer helped then please "accept" it to show some reputation points love!

Comment: In your revised query adding the distinct got the total down to 800 for trynow campaign from 1000.

Comment: You're right. I've removed it! I'd have to say what you are doing with the comissions table to be able to comment further.

Comment: removing the distinct and adding affiliate_commissions creates even a stranger SUM result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200eb/7.

Comment: That's because you don't have appropriate linkage between the commissions and the individual transactions, so rows are being counted more than once.

For this to work in one query, you'd need to tie each affiliate_commissions record to a specific transaction or tracking.

Otherwise, you will have to go back to a more complex query with derived tables, where you sum each entity seperately.

Might be time to review whether you really need to fragment your table structure so much. It seems very complex for what it is.

Comment: how would you approach the linkage between commissions and transactions, their connection is a unique trader_id that has many commissions and transactions.

Comment: Link on the transaction, not on the trader. You can extrapolate the trader link by linking trader > transaction > commission

Comment: I'm not sure it works with my logic, a trader deposits an amount (transaction_id) he can deposit again to his account to add funds, and then trades on the platform, from these trades (trade_id) the affiliate(aff_id) receives commissions.